# Convert Regular Expression pattern from Javascript to PCRE (perl)

Tags: javascript, c++, regex, pcre

This is my javascript regex pattern:

```
    url = "http://www.amazon.com/gp";    
    hostname = /^((\\w+):\\/\\/\\/?)?((\\w+):?(\\w+)?@)?([^\\/\\?:]+):?(\\d+)?(\\/?[^\\?#;\\|]+)?([;\\|])?([^\\?#]+)?\\??([^#]+)?#?(\\w*)/.exec(url) || [];
// would return "www.amazon.com"
```

- the above regex extracting the hostname from a given url.
  I need this line to work using pcre (c++).
  as you can see, I already added another '\' to each '\' but its still doesn't work.

what are the additional changes I need to do to make it work in pcre code instead of javascript? or maybe it isn't possible and I need to build entirely new pattern to make it work in pcre?

this is a simple version of my code:

```
int main(void)
{
    string text = "http://www.amazon.com";
    string hostname;
    pcrecpp::RE re("^((\\w+):\\/\\/\\/?)?((\\w+):?(\\w+)?@)?([^\\/\\?:]+):?(\\d+)?(\\/?[^\\?#;\\|]+)?([;\\|])?([^\\?#]+)?\\??([^#]+)?#?(\\w*)");
    if(re.PartialMatch(text, &hostname)) 
    {
        std::cout << "match: " << hostname << "\n";
    }else{
        std::cout << "no match. \n";
    }       
    return 0;
}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

There's no need to convert it, the only thing you have to take care of is the escaping and the / delimiter.

Do note that a regular expression might not be what you want to use here. Or atleast... not like this directly. There are lots of url parsing libraries that are a lot better suited for this task. [HTParse](http://www.w3.org/Library/src/HTParse) for example.

Your C++ code should work but your regex has a lot of optional groups so it's hard to be sure in what group the hostname will end up.

As hacky as it may be, my edit works for this input

```
string text = "http://www.amazon.com";
string tmp;
string hostname;
pcrecpp::RE re("^((\\w+):\\/\\/\\/?)?((\\w+):?(\\w+)?@)?([^\\/\\?:]+):?(\\d+)?(\\/?[^\\?#;\\|]+)?([;\\|])?([^\\?#]+)?\\??([^#]+)?#?(\\w*)");
if(re.PartialMatch(text, &tmp, &tmp, &tmp, &tmp, &tmp, &hostname))
{
    std::cout << "match: " << hostname << "\n";
}else{
    std::cout << "no match. \n";
}
```

Comment: what should i do to the "/ delimiter"?

Comment: @BillyONeal: that's not correct, in the C++ version of PCRE you don't need delimiters. Also, you usually don't have to use / as a delimiter, most other delimiters will also work.

Answer (score 1):

```
"^((\\w+):\\/\\/\\/?)?((\\w+):?(\\w+)?@)?([^\\/\\?:]+):?(\\d+)?(\\/?[^\\?#;\\|]+)?([;\\|])?([^\\?#]+)?\\??([^#]+)?#?(\\w*)"
```